# Android-Kotlin: How to avoid having the screen shifting up when dialog is shown?

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, dialog

I have implemented a very simple dialog as shown in the image below (this image is taken from the Pixel 3a emulator in Android Studio):

[image: Pixel 3a Emulator]

And it works well on most devices, but on a single, physical device (an LG G8 ThinQ) it is giving me a strange shift at the top as you can see from the screenshots below:

Here is the screen before the dialog appears:

[image: LG before dialog]

Then, here is the screen once the dialog has appeared:

[image: LG during dialog]

And here is when the dialog has been closed:

[image: LG after dialog]

As you can see, the screen remains shifted at the top, out of boundaries. I have tried everything to avoid that but to no avail.

Here is the function calling the dialog:

```
 fun createNewFolderDialog() {
            val supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager = (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
            CreateNewFolderDialogFragment().show(supportFragmentManager, "CreateNewFolderFragment")

        }
```

And here is the dialog class:

```
class CreateNewFolderDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {



    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

       

        getDialog()!!.getWindow()?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

        val dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_new_folder_dialog, container, false)

        fun submitNewFolderName() {

            val edit = dialog.findViewById(R.id.folder_name) as EditText
            val text = edit.text.toString()

            if (text != "") {
                getDialog()?.cancel()

                //Creates new folder...                

            }

        }

        //Set up listeners...
        val cnlButton: Button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel)
        cnlButton.setOnClickListener {
            
            getDialog()?.cancel()

           //Cancel...



        }

        val okButton: Button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok)
        okButton.setOnClickListener {
            //Submit new folder...

        }

        return dialog
    }



    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        var width = 400
        width = width.toPx()
        
        dialog!!.window?.setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        dialog!!.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)       

        dialog!!.window?.decorView?.apply {
            // Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
            // SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
            // a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
            // hide the navigation bar.
            //systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

            systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                    SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

        }

    }



}
```

And finally, here is the XML of the dialog layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentFl"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="60dp">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner">




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/new_folder_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="New Music Folder Name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/new_folder_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="Enter the new name for the folder"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/new_folder_title" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/folder_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Folder name"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/new_folder_subtitle" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_buttons_background"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/vsm_links"
            app:backgroundTint="@null"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_ok"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/folder_name" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_buttons_background"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="@color/vsm_disabled"
            app:backgroundTint="@null"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_cancel"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/folder_name" />




    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Does it behaves the same if you used `inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_new_folder_dialog, container)` for the dialog?

Comment: At a guess it's related to you trying to hide the status bar at the top - it seems like it's shifting up by the same amount (so the top of the window is now at the top of the actual screen, and the status bar is on top of it). Any reason why you're doing all that stuff with the dialog? It looks like a standard one mostly!

Comment: @Zain Do you mean with the "false"? If so, I just tried, and doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @cactustictacs I do all that to avoid having the bottom navigation bar showing up on some devices because I want to stay in full screen. I also tried a simple dialog without all that stuff, and the problem still appears. I have also tried to just remove stuff full screen stuff you are referring to, and the problem persists.

Comment: I forgot to include the XML layout for the dialog, maybe that's giving you some clues. I'll edit my original post to include that as well.

Comment: Do you set `android:windowSoftInputMode` ? .. I see you used `dialog!!.window?.setSoftInputMode` .. can you remove this .. also disable the underneath flags for a while

Comment: @Zain What do you mean about "android:windowSoftInputMode"? Is that in the manifest? Please, tell me more. I have tried some stuff over there too but made no difference. About the "dialog!!.window?.setSoftInputMode", as I said in my previous comment, I have tried to remove that code, and doesn't change anything, the problem persists on that device. But that code helps to show the keyboard as soon as the dialog is shown.

Comment: @FabrizioFerrari when you close your dialog again on that device, can you pull the activity back down under the status bar? Like has it scrolled up, or is the activity now at the very top of the screen, with the status bar overlaid on it? Because in your "before" pic, it's below the status bar, i.e. the normal non-fullscreen/immersive layout. So it looks like your dialog is setting different flags or something. I can't really help you fix it, but I'd say you probably shouldn't be trying to hide the UI like that - it's a bad experience and as you're noticing, it's a bit screwy and unpredictable

Comment: @cactustictacs Yes, I can, I see no usability issues there. I am sure you are right about the dialog setting up some flags I am not aware of... but which ones? Just to let you know, if I change activity (i.e. I switch to another app or get back to the main system screen), and then back to the app, or I tap the square button in the bottom system navigation bar and re-select my app, it gets restored correctly.

Comment: @FabrizioFerrari restored to what though? In your "before" pic, the status bar is visible - it's not fullscreen / immersive like your emulator pic. That's not correct, right? It's also visible in your "after" pics, it's just being drawn over the activity instead of the window making room for it. So your dialog is setting different flags on the window than the activity is (you'll have to compare them), but it's also not behaving the same way as on your emulator. You're getting inconsistencies from doing this - at least check it's also happening on an emulator with the same API version as the LG

Comment: @cactustictacs Thank you! You just suggested me the solution to it! Please, see my answer below... thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you to @cactustictacs for his hints. He was right, the problem had something to do with the different API on the LG device. In all the emulated devices, I had API 30 (Android 11) and everything worked fine, whereas on the LG I have API 28 (Android Pie) and I overlooked that key difference. I created new emulated devices with API 28 and 29, and yes, I could reproduce the same issue on those devices as well.

Then, I could resolve the issue by simply observing a MutableLiveData variable from the main activity set to "true" every time the dialog is closed, in order to restore the full-screen view with the following code in the main activity:

```
 binding.fullscreenContent.systemUiVisibility =
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

And voila', the problem is now solved. The shift occurs only when the dialog is shown, but as soon as it is closed, the view is restored in full screen.

Thanks again to everyone for helping me.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! You should probably check other API versions on emulators too though - at the very least, the version you've defined as your ``minSdk``. There might be other weirdness you need to account for

Comment: @cactustictacs Good point! I'll make sure to test as you have suggested. Thanks again!